# Loop over subplots

Tags: matlab

Somehow, the title, xlabel, ylabel, ylim and xlim does not stay fixed in the script below, how do I fix this?

```
    x = 0:0.01:1;

figure
p1 = subplot(2,1,1);
xlabel(p1, '$x$','Interpreter','LaTex', 'Fontsize', 16);
ylabel(p1, '$\sin(x+t)$','Interpreter','LaTex', 'Fontsize', 16);
title(p1, 'Sine','Interpreter','LaTex', 'Fontsize', 20);
ylim(p1, [-1 2]) 
xlim(p1, [0 1]) 

p2 = subplot(2,1,2);
xlabel(p2, '$x$','Interpreter','LaTex', 'Fontsize', 16);
ylabel(p2, '$\cos(x+t)$','Interpreter','LaTex', 'Fontsize', 16);
title(p2, 'Cosine','Interpreter','LaTex', 'Fontsize', 20);
ylim(p2, [-2 1])
xlim(p2, [0 1]) 

for t = 0:0.1:2
    plot(p1, x, sin(x+t))      
    plot(p2, x, cos(x+t))
    pause(0.1)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, since you haven't got `hold on` or `hold all`, when you replot in the loop everything is reset.  Since you only want to change one set of values in each graph, you can use `set` rather than `plot` here to get around the issue.

First, after each subplot is called, plot the initial graph and take a handle for it:

```
p1 = subplot(2,1,1);
h1 = plot(p1,x,sin(x);
```

Then continue on setting up the labels, etc, as you already do.

In the loop, to replace the data in your existing graph:

```
for t = 0.1:0.1:2
    set(h1,'Ydata',sin(x+t))      
    set(h2,'Ydata',cos(x+t)) 
    pause(0.1)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Now I want to have two plots in the top figure, but

    set(h1,'Ydata',sin(x+t),'Ydata',sin(x-t))

does not work. How can I do this?

Comment: You will need to set the data for each of the plots separately, I think. Depending how you set the inital plot, your h1 may be size 2 x 1, and then you should call set twice - `set(h1(1)...)` and `set(h1(2)...)`.